# splitting char[] into separate char[] using delimiter in java

Tags: java, char

I have a situation in Java where I want to split the char[] into separate char[] which is having `|` as delimiter. 
Example :

```
char[] input = { 'a', 'r', '|','t', 'i', '|','s', 't' };
```

given **input** character array should be split in to 3 different character arrays like :-

```
result1 = {'a','r'}
result2 = {'t','i'}
result3 = {'s','t'}
```

> Note: The delimiter occurrence is fixed and for security reasons I am not allowed to use strings here.

How can I do this in java?

Comment: So... do you not know how to read arrays? How to create arrays? How to compare characters? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Would all the resulting arrays be named as `result`{number}? Ex: `result4`,`result5` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do not know how much this new char[]'s will be I think it will be hard to do. Your compiler needs to know how many char[] (named and accessible I suppose) you need.

My first idea was to concat it to string and then split it using your delimiter char. But you wrote that you can't/don't want to use strings.

It's rather workaround but you could create an array of char[] arrays. Using some kind for or foreach that will add those chars into elements of base array.

Please give me a comment if it is what you're looking for and if not try to add some more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best solved by collecting the resulting char arrays in a `List<char[]>` (even if the number of splits is known beforehand).

The split itself can be performed by stepping through input array and comparing the character against the delimiter. If a delimiter is found, you extract the sequence of characters between the current position and the position of the last found delimiter into a new `char[]`, and add that to the List. Repeat until the end of the input array is reached.

If the number of splits is known beforehand, you could use a `char[][]` preallocated to that number, but you'd have to track yourself where to insert the next extracted `char[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You may only need to track the indices of the delimiter and then you can assign the corresponding characters to your new result char arrays.

for example, you can try some code like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] input = { 'a','i', '|','s', 'r','d', '|','t', 'c','i', '|','s', 't' };

    int[] indexOfDelimiter=new int[input.length];
    indexOfDelimiter[0]=-1;
    int j=1; //track of delimiter index
    for (int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        if (input[i]=='|'){
            indexOfDelimiter[j++]=i; // get the position of the delimiter
        }
    }
    indexOfDelimiter[j]=input.length;

    //now you can get the result char arrays like:
    ArrayList<char[]> results=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
        char[] chars=Arrays.copyOfRange(input,indexOfDelimiter[i]+1, indexOfDelimiter[i+1]);
        results.add(chars);
    }

    //for retrieving the char arrays, you can do like this:
    for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){
        System.out.println(results.get(i));
    }
    // the output is :
    // ai
    // srd
    // tci
    // st
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 to the <strike>rescue</strike> obfuscation!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] input = { 'a', 'r', '|','t', 'i', '|','s', 't' };

        List<Spliterator<Character>> spliterators= new DelimiterSpliterator(input, '|').tryAllSplits();

        List<char[]> splits= spliterators.stream().collect(ArrayList<char[]>::new, (result, element) -> result.add(((DelimiterSpliterator) element).toCharArray()), ArrayList<char[]>::addAll);

        for (char[] split : splits) {
            System.out.println(split);
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Spliterator;

public class DelimiterSpliterator implements Spliterator<Character> {
    private final char[] array;
    private final char delimiter;
    private int start;
    private final int end;

    public DelimiterSpliterator(char[] array, char delimiter) {
        this(array, delimiter, 0, array.length);
    }

    private DelimiterSpliterator(char[] array, char delimiter, int start, int end) {
        this.array = array;
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public char[] toCharArray() {
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, start, end);
    }

    public List<Spliterator<Character>> tryAllSplits() {
        // Collects all splits.
        List<Spliterator<Character>> result = new ArrayList<>();            
        Spliterator<Character> s = trySplit();
        while (s != null) {
            result.add(s);
            s = trySplit();
        }
        result.add(this);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return IMMUTABLE | ORDERED | SIZED | SUBSIZED;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return end-start;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Character> action) {
        if (start < end) {
            action.accept(array[start++]);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<Character> trySplit() {
        // Returns a new Spliterator that cannot be split further, from left to right.
        for (int i = start; i < end - 1; i++) {
            if (array[i] == delimiter) {
                final int origStart = start;
                start = i + 1;
                return new DelimiterSpliterator(array, delimiter, origStart, i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note: possible performance issue related to auto-boxing/unboxing as mentioned [in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html).
Streams are good if the input is large and especially if the resulting order doesn't matter (the stream can be parallel, trySplit can be less deterministic, etc.)